# Dataconnection to MySql (ADO.NET) - ConsoleApplication C# vs2015

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015, ado.net, data-connections

After days of research and having found lots of information (even here on stackoverflow), I'm still not able to add a dataconnection to my local MySQL-Server. I tried different versions of the MySQL Connector/NET and the MySQL for Visual Studio-Tool, but MySql does still not appear in the connection-wizard.

Does anyone have another idea I could try? Could the problem be in my App.config, or should I change the version of the .NET Framework? Is it better to use the .dlls of nuget or the once from the Connector?

Actually I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Windows 10
- Connector/NET 6.9.9
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6
- MySQL Server 5.7.16

I have included the following .dlls:

- MySql.Data
- MySql.Web
- MySql.Data.Entity
- MySql.Data.Entity.EF6

My ConnectionString looks like the following:

```
<add name="serverlocation" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=*xxx*;Uid=*yyy*;Pwd=*zzz*;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the connectionstring that's causing problems maybe it's easier to try it out with the .udl file, see [Test a Database Connection String using NotePad](http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/test-a-database-connection-string-using-notepad).

If the problem is in your code, you should submit the smallest program that can demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I tried the method with the .udl file but there is no MySql as provider (I don't know if that should be there). A

Comment: I don't think the code is the problem, because it does not work with an empty project eighter.